# Laravel notification class not pass variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-notification

I can't pass `sendSms` to `toHistory` method. It is always set as `false`. How can I do it properly?

```
class SendMessage extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $sendSms;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        $this->sendSms = true;
    }

    public function toHistory($notifiable) {
        echo $this->sendSms; //return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the [official Laravel Notifications doc's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels) it appears that when overriding the `via($notifiable)` method, you're suppose to return an array of channels the Notification can be sent through. So you probably want to return `['nexmo']` assuming nexmo is the sms service you want to use.

Comment: Yes, I return nexmo: `return array_merge($this->sendSms ? ['nexmo'] : ['mail'], HistoryChannel::class]);` (in my post I added only a part of code) but `sendSms` set in `via()` to TRUE loose value and in `toHistory()` has FALSE value. I don't know why. @alexkb